# Get ParentViewController from pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a page-based application, consisting of collectionViews within each ViewController. I then have an viewController coming off the barButton on the pageView which leads to an add page for the user to add their data. I am trying to find a way to determine what the source view controller was so that I can append and reload the correct ViewController. Below is my UIPageView and AddSubject classes:

AddSubject.swift:

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework


class AddSubjectView: UIViewController {

    // collectionView
    @IBOutlet var colourPicker: UICollectionView!

    var source = UIViewController()

    // source of colours to use in the colour collectionView
    private var data = collectionViewColors.createColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // gesture recognizer to determine when the user has tapped anywhere but the text field

        let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddSubjectView.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    }

    @IBAction func addPressed(sender: AnyObject) {




    }

    func addData() {




    }

    // dismiss keyboard when the user taps away from the text field (called above with #selector)
    func dismissKeyboard() {

        view.endEditing(true)
    }

// mandatory methods to display collectionView data in the collectionView
}
extension AddSubjectView: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colourCell



        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]


        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    }



}
```

PageViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    // created for use in the function which determines the title of the navigationBar
    var arrayIndex: Int = 0
    // reference for later function to determine title of navigationBar
    var pageControl = UIPageControl.self

    // NSUserDefaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    // set of viewControllers (based on their storyboard ID)

    private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newDayViewController("monday"),
                self.newDayViewController("tuesday"),
                self.newDayViewController("wednesday"),
                self.newDayViewController("thursday"),
                self.newDayViewController("friday"),
                self.newDayViewController("saturday"),
                self.newDayViewController("sunday")
        ]
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        // setting the datasource & Delegate of the UIPageViewController
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self




        // set the first viewController for the pageView (monday as it is the first in the set)

        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .Forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)


        }

    }





    // function to add view controllers
    // function will only instantiateViewControllers which have a storyboard id containing 'day' e.g Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

    private func newDayViewController(day: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(day)")
    }




    // set the navigationBar title to the dayViewController's title
    // if the user is looking at orderedViewControllers[1], then the title of that day is "Tuesday"

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if (!completed) {
            return
        }


        if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
            let arrayIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) {
            switch arrayIndex {
            case 0:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Monday"
                self.navigationItem.title = "Monday"
                break

            case 1:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Tuesday"
                self.navigationItem.title = "Tuesday"
                break

            case 2:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Wednesday"
                self.navigationItem.title = "Wednesday"
                break

            case 3:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Thursday"
                break
            case 4:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Friday"
                break

            case 5:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Saturday"
                break

            case 6:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Sunday"
                break

            default:
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Timetable"


            }
        }
    }
}
// Mandatory functions and setup for the pageViewController to work

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return orderedViewControllers.last
        }
        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count


        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return orderedViewControllers.first
        }
        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
    // set number of viewControllers to be presented
    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return orderedViewControllers.count
    }
    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
            firstViewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) else {
                return 0
        }
        return firstViewControllerIndex
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use one addSubject view rather than have to create barButton items for all of the individual viewControllers and link them to their own individual viewController.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Are you just wanting a way to determine which view controller is the current view controller in your pageViewController?

Comment: Kind of, I'm trying to determine what viewcontroller / page view index the user was on when they pressed the add button, so I can tell where to store the new data. I hope what I just said is a little more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current on screen UIViewController in your UIPageViewController, you can implement the UIPageViewControllerDelegate protocol method "didFinishAnimating". I'm using the following example in one of my apps to achieve this.

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    let currentVC = pageViewController
        .viewControllers![pageViewController.viewControllers!.count - 1]
}
```

If you need the index, it is easiest to create your own UIViewController subclass with an index property on it. Then in your "viewControllerBeforeViewController" and "viewControllerAfterViewController" methods, can assign the index before returning the ViewController

example:

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,      viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) ->   UIViewController? {

    let currentDetailVC: RAFeedDetailViewController = viewController as! RAFeedDetailViewController

    return vcAtIndex(currentDetailVC.index - 1)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentDetailVC: RAFeedDetailViewController = viewController as! RAFeedDetailViewController

    return vcAtIndex(currentDetailVC.index + 1)
}

func vcAtIndex(index: Int) -> RAFeedDetailViewController? {

    guard index < self.dataSourceItems.count - 1 && index >= 0 else { return nil }


    /* insert logic here to get the correct view controller */
    let detailVC: RAArticleDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(RAArticleDetailViewController.self)) as! RAArticleDetailViewController

    detailVC.index = index

     return vc
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go

Comment: No problem. I just added a few changes to make it a little more generic since I just pulled it out of my project. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, awesome, Thank you !

Comment: No worries. Happy to help!